# Java HashObjObjMap<K, V> vs HashMap<K, V>

Tags: java, hashmap, koloboke

What is the difference between Koloboke `HashObjObj<K, V>` and Java util `HashMap<K, V>`?

I am aware of the performance that Koloboke provides but there might be instances that K/V turn out to be a Integer/Long. Generally if known `HashLongObjMap` would be recommended but what happens when K/V come in as generics. From what I understand using `HashLongObjMap` uses `long` primitive as the key but what are the differences that come in when `HashObjObjMap<Long, V>` is used?

Eg:

> `HashLongObjMap<V> map1 = HashLongObjMaps.newImmutableMap();`

Vs

> `HashObjObjMap<K, V> map2 = HashObjObjMaps.newImmutableMap();`

Comment: http://java-performance.info/large-hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove/

Comment: @assylias: Seems using `HashObjObjMap<K,V>` would hit the performance even if K is `Long`. Isn't there a way the library itself calls `HashLongObjMap` or `HashIntObjMap` if `K` is one of the data types? May be I'll try look out for a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `HashObjObjMap` and `java.util.HashMap` is algorithm and itnernal memory layout. `HashObjObjMap` is an open-addressing hash table with linear probing, storing keys and values in the same flat `Object[]` array, in interspersed order: [key1, value1, key2, value2, ...]. `Entry` objects don't exist, they are created only when required by `Map` API (i. e. `entrySet()` iteration). `HashMap` is a hash table with separate chaining, keys and values are stored in separate `Entry` objects.

`HashLongObjMap` stores keys as primitive `long`s, `HashObjObjMap` has ordinary `Object` keys.

`HashObjObjMap<Long, V>` cannot call `HashLongObjMap` internally because they have slightly different contract, e. g. the latter cannot hold `null` key. Also I don't see much sense in it, if you need `long` keys you should just explicitly use `HashLongObjMap` yourself instead of `HashObjObjMap` and relying on some implicit "optimizations".

Comment: Need it this way as it is not guaranteed that the keys will be long. `It might be short, int, byte, etc`. Using **Obj** to cover all would impact performance, although using **long** for all cases is another alternative. But the data set is huge and so I'm willing to keep it flexible. It is required in the middle of a method. Interface/Abstract class and separate implementations make it too complex due to good number of permutations and other associated limitations.

Comment: I don't see how ObjObj<Long,...> resolving as LongObj would solve this problem. Common base of all LongObj, IntObj, ShortObj maps is simply `java.util.Map` (raw). You can use it